# How to get the value of a MemberExpression?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, lambda

I am writing a fluent SQL interface (yes, just like LINQ to Entities) and I am trying to get the value of a MemberExpression but am having trouble getting the samples I have found on the web to work.

For example, say I have the following code:

```
var test = true;
var search = Search.Create()
    .To(to)
    .From(from)
    .Where( m => m.BooleanField == test );
```

In my Where() method, I am extracting the left and right sides of the Expression. I have right as a MemberExpression and am trying to compile it such that it evaluates to true, like this:

```
var objectMember = Expression.Convert(right, typeof(object));
var getterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(objectMember);
var getter = getterLambda.Compile();
```

I am expecting getter to be 'true', but it is 'NULL'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, `Compile` will return a `Func` which you then need to `Invoke` to get the actual result of the expression.

Comment: Aren't you meant to pass a parameter list to `Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>()` as well as the Expression?

Comment: I tried using getter.Invoke() but this still returns null.

Comment: Doh! How stupid I am. I was setting this field to NULL in my code. Thanks for your help.